# Sybase ASE 15.5 and which JPA implementation?

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures, database-schema, sap-ase

Which JPA implementation supports the following features against Sybase ASE 15.5 and how well?

- Schema import (there is an existing server running; Hibernate does not even find existing tables.)
- Schema export (maybe for new stuff; Hibernate seems to have no support for UNIVARCHAR)
- stored procedure support
- stored procedure import? (like schema import)
- UNIVARCHAR type support (Hibernate does not per-se generate UNIVARCHAR columns, how about OpenJPA?)
- TEXT type support.
- schema migration including data migration tools

Any other pros/cons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA is a runtime, not a development tool.  Most of your questions seem to be tooling related, for which I would suggest using Eclipse JPA (Dali).

You can use any schema tools you want with any JPA provider, as long as they generate standard JPA metadata.

EclipseLink supports calling stored procedures on Sybase, including output parameters and multiple resultsets.
Any JPA provider should work at runtime with UNIVARCHAR and TEXT, to have the type used in default schema generation you would set them in the @Column columnDefinition, or customize the SybasePlatform in EclipseLink to use the type by default.